# Cisco Command to display link status

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-ios, cli

I am having a bit of a brain freeze. I would like to know the command that displays the link status when a network cable is unplugged from the switch port. What is the command name?

Comment: There isn't a "cable presence detect" on any Cisco switch I'm aware of. (there's SFP detect, but no cable sense) Link up/down is all you can see.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way on Cisco switches is:

```
show int status
```

This will show you the link status for all ports 
The 45xx line has also some additional useful commands:

```
show int link
```

which will show you the last time the link was active.
Also you can use (it is disruptive for the port):

```
test cable-diagnostics tdr interface xx/yy
```

and then

```
show cable-diagnostics tdr
```

This will give you an approximation of the length of the attached cable

Answer (score 4):

**sho ip int brief** will give you a list of all the interfaces and their status as well as protocol. It will not show you if a cable is "unplugged" but will tell you if something is plugged into the interface and sending frames.

**sho int** Will allow you to see if an interface is UP and whether or not protocol is also UP.

If you are just looking to monitor status changes on the terminal, **term monitor**

Comment: And: `show log` (if logging is enabled)

Comment: That's it! Term monitor was the command I was looking for! Thanks @Hal